# Error running Ipython notebook on commandline (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to run an ipython notebook on ubuntu commandline: ###

```
$ ipython assignment1.ipynb 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/path/to/notebook/assignment1.ipynb in <module>()

36   { 

37    "cell_type": "code", 

---> 38    "execution_count": null,

39    "metadata": {

40     "collapsed": false

NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

EDIT:

I want to open it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scF53.png) notebook in terminal

But what I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilDvF.png)

Comment: What's about the code itself?

Comment: code works perfectly well in jupyter notebook. But now I want it to run on command line so that I can run the code on Server.

Comment: If it's works fine, what's the question about? We could only speculate about the problem without clear vision.

Comment: I want to run the notebook in the terminal by 
$ ipython assignment.ipynb
but this command shows me an error as shown above
(This is not an error in code, this is some problem maybe with my ipython settings, version ,...)
So my question is that what should I do in order to fix this issue

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Please see the edits.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run an IPython notebook, so your command is wrong. `ipython notebook Playing_with_TensorFlow.ipynb` should do the trick.

> IPython Notebook ( http://ipython.org/notebook.html ) is a web based extension of iPython.  It's very powerful and convenient and It allows you to mix code, annotation, text, figures into a single interactive document.

[Source](https://kb.brandeis.edu/display/SCI/How+to+open+a+notebook+file+with+iPython+notebook)

And in the future, please do not post screenshots of your problem, but type them out, see the [how to ask a question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).